# downgrade ubuntu 14.10 to ubuntu 14.04 or 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, libav

Well i installed **ubuntu 14.10** with **gnome** deskotp environment but during installation of `opencv`. I am having issues with `libav` as recent `ubuntu` uses `api version 11` and I need `api version 9` so i want to downgrade to ubuntu14.04 or better 12.04 is there any way to do so

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way would be to get an .iso or DVD/CD of the OS and install it yourself. To my knowledge there is no downgrade tool.